# How many Nexus Integration Teams?

Tags: scrum, nexus

With 19 scrum teams. The PO selects 6 goals for the sprint. Cross Team Refinement shows multiple dependencies across all 6 goals. The scrum teams plan and it's achievable. Multiple Dependency Charts are created. 8 teams are involved in the 6 goals and not in all of the goals and not all of the time.

How many Nexus Integration Teams are required ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As defined in [the Nexus Guide](https://www.scrum.org/resources/online-nexus-guide), there is 1 Nexus Integration Team per Nexus. However, "a Nexus is a group of approximately three to nine Scrum Teams that work together to deliver a single product". Since you have 19 Scrum Teams, which is over twice the defined size from the Nexus Guide and much larger than "approximately nine", you should think about how your products and teams are structured and reorganize into smaller Nexuses, with perhaps some stand-alone Scrum Teams.

Comment: Yes that's what I thought.